# Select dynamic set of columns from dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am attempting to write a simple Scala program that will ultimately take an argument that is a comma separated list of columns.  The goal is to simply select that dynamic set of columns from a giant dataframe into a new dataframe.  If I hard code the list of columns, this works:

```
df.select((Array("colA","colB")).map(df(_)) : _*  ).show
```

So now I'm trying to get from a string like `"colA,colB"` to that.  Here's my latest effort:

```
val cols = "colA,colB"
//split to an array, end up with each element quoted
val colList = cols.split(",").mkString("'", "', '", "'")
df.select((Array(colList)).map(df(_)) : _*  ).show
```

That gives me the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
Cannot resolve column name "'colA', 'colB'" among (<actual column list>)
```

This is, of course, correct. There is no column named that.  I've tried a few other different things, but I keep getting this error.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is enough to select the right columns :

```
val cols = "colA,colB"
val colList = cols.split(",") // This is already the right Array
df.select(colList).map(df(_)) : _*  ).show
```

Do not use :

```
val colList = cols.split(",")
val new_string = colList.mkString("'", "', '", "'") // This is "'colA', 'colB'"
df.select(Array(new_string)).map(df(_)) : _*  ).show // Error
```

Comment: Man, I was seriously over-complicating this, thanks!  I'll accept it as soon as SO lets me.